# Unable to generate Session ID with correct cookie params

Tags: php, session-cookies

I am currently creating a PHP login system and figured I would, as research suggested, use a session ID cookie for this. Of course I wanted to make it as secure as possible and therefore I am setting the httponly cookie param to true.

Now the problem is if I try to set my session cookie params before I call the session_start() function it appears to not create a session id cookie at all whereas if I do it the other way around it does. Of course if I do it the other way around the params are not being set.

So to clearify, this does not even generate a session ID cookie:

```
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 
    $secure,
    $httponly);

session_start();
```

And this does generate one, but without the proper params. (I confirmed this by checking my cookie information in my browser)

```
session_start();
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 
    $secure,
    $httponly);
```

I cannot think of any reason why this would happen and would not know how to fix this. 
If anyone could help me out, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the values you are trying to set, what is `$secure` for example?

Comment: Secure and httponly are both true. I used the example they provided here [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Comment: And are you loading the page over https / does the domain have an ssl certificate?

Comment: No just basic http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are loading the page over http and not over https, you cannot set the `$secure` parameter to `true`. If you do that, you will never receive the cookie as you have just specified that the cookie can only be sent over a secure connection.

So you need to use the default or set it to `false` manually:

```
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params(
    $cookieParams["lifetime"],
    $cookieParams["path"], 
    $cookieParams["domain"], 
    false,    // $cookieParams["secure"] will also work if you have not modified php.ini to set it to true
    $httponly
);

session_start();
```